# Perform a hard close of iOS app and reopen with saved state in simulator w/ automation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcuitest

I'm attempting to automate a hard close and relaunch of an iOS application while retaining state in the simulator.

Googling tells me to add a button to my app to call `exit(0)`, but that's resetting app state despite a number of threads saying it doesn't ([although Apple said it's unreliable for this a long time ago](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1561/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007952)).

Another thread said to use `abort`, but that's akin to throwing an exception and definitely not the right thing.

Performing the [automated] manual steps (double click the Home button and swipe the app up to death) disconnects the debugger so another option failed.

Answer (score 0):

The correct procedure for testing state restoration is: click the Home button on the simulator *once* so that the app backgrounds and saves state. Now, back in Xcode, stop and relaunch.

Comment: I'm trying to do this via an automation suite; manual steps are not an option.I suppose I could try terminating the app and reactiving via automation once it's backgrounded, but something tells me that won't work. Is my assumption wrong?

Comment: I don't know what an automation suite is. Both those steps can be automated (e.g. with `osascript` / AppleScript) but I have no idea what you're using. You _must_ go normally into the background _somehow_ or you won't save state.

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate a click on the Home button like that

`XCUIDevice.shared.press(.home)`

And then call this function to launch your app with

`XCUIApplication().launch()`

According to the `launch()` documentation, it should terminate your app and relaunch it :

> ```
>  * Launches the application synchronously. On return the application ready to handle events. If the
>  * application is already running, the existing instance will be terminated to ensure a clean state
>  * for the launched instance.
>  *
>  * Any failure in the launch sequence will be reported as a test failure and the test will be halted
>  * at that point.
> ```

Comment: Just tried this. Unfortunately, this reinstalls the app and clears out existing data.

Comment: Also tried using `activate()`, but that amounted to only backgrounding the app (I need to hard close it).

Comment: Did you try to use `XCUIApplication().terminate()` ?

Comment: Yep. Tried every combination of `activate`, `launch`, with and without `terminate`.

Comment: `activate` was a soft close, `activate` with a `terminate` is functionally the same as `launch` (hard close, but then reinstall and wiped data).

Comment: Hum, so, I don't think it's possible right now. I tried to simulate a double home button tap to try automating the app killing process but the double home button tap doesn't work.

Comment: I was able to do that manually, but it also wiped the app data.